# Manually updating a database schema created by EF code-first

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, database-schema

I have a database that was created with the Entity Framework's code first approach.

Currently it has just 5 tables. One of the tables, called `Incidents`, backs the `Incident` C# class. The class needs to get just one additional property - `bool HasClaim`.

I know that since the DB is initialized with `DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges`, the moment I will try to initialize with an adjusted entity class, my DB data will get purged, and a new database will be created.

What is the simplest path for me to make this class/schema update? (in general, like: read data into an XML, recreate DB and manually, from C# code, place new entities.)

P.S.
Maybe I can go ahead and create a Database model from current DB, adjust it, adjust the code, and reconfig to no longer use code-first? I seems like code-first currently is only good if you are 100% sure you are not to change the models after the DB goes into production. But with a successful projects, it is never the case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Entity Framework Migrations:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/01/12/ef-4-3-beta-1-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

Another approach is to only have the DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges strategy in debug builds (for test environments) and then scripting schema changes with another tool for upgrading production environments.

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

The best way is to use `EntityFramework.SqlMigrations`

You can modify your `Models` and `DbSet` and migrate the changes to your database without drop and recreate your Database.

> #### It is avaliable using [NuGet](http://nuget.org)
>
> #### Install-Package EntityFramework.SqlMigrations

Scott Hanselman wrote a nice blog post about that.

#### More Information

- [Scott Hanselman - Entity Framework Code First Migrations](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EntityFrameworkCodeFirstMigrationsAlphaNuGetPackageOfTheWeek10.aspx)
- [NuGet Package Manager](http://nuget.org)

Comment: dknaack, although your answer was initially the one that has led me to results, I should note that .SqlMigrations package is deprecated now and is no longer available. The one available is a part of PreRelease Entity Framework 4.3. Since it will be fair from my point of view, I will remark the question as answered by granaker.